# In Kivy, RecycleView, how to scroll to the last item?

Tags: kivy

I have a `RecycleView` widget with a list of items, and I want to always scroll to the last item when I append a new item to my `list_view.data`. Using `scroll_to` by referencing the last `Row` widget doesn't work (as also reported in this unfixed issue https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5014):

```
list_view.scroll_to(list_view.children[0].children[-1], animate=False)
```

The error is `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'is_triggered'`

Does `scroll_to` not work with `RecycleView` at all? Is there a work-around then?

Answer (score 1):

```
class YourScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.your_recycleview.scroll_y = 0 #### This is all you need
```

If you use something like this in the python portion when youre writing your functions it will set the scroll position to 0. Recycle view is on a scale of 0-1 so you can also us scroll_y = 1 to go to the top of the list